# I have a problem in SQL Server 2000 when searching for a term in farsi

Tags: sql-server-2000, persian, farsi

I have a problem in SQL Server 2000 with farsi search.

I have a table with `nvarchar` fields with unicode (farsi) values and need to search content of that with unicode (farsi) text.

I am using

```
select * from table1
where fieldname like '%[farsi word]%'
```

My farsi word is exist but return 0 row.

What can I do?

thanks all.

Comment: Are you using the `[]` characters in your query or is this just an example?

Comment: Are you doing this select from a programming language or SQL console? You should also check that the table / column character set is correct and if you are using Java or something like that you should define something for ex. in Java for MySQL: jdbc:mysql://server/database?characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: no i dont use [],i test this code in query analyser and my programming language (Delphi), but it worked correctly for en word and numeric values,have a problem just for farsi value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `NVARCHAR` fields, you should also use Unicode when searching! You do this by prepending a `N` before your search term:

```
select * from table1
where fieldname like N'%[farsi word]%'
```

Also: be aware the if your search term begins with a `%` wildcard, you've basically disabled all use of any indices there might be to speed up your search. Using `LIKE %...%` for searching will always result in a pretty slow table scan....